# Sort objects by hit_count.hits

Tags: django

Using django-hitcount to count views with no issues. Now, how do I sort a QS by hits? For example, have a bunch of different animals:

```
class Dog(models.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    age = models.IntField()

class DogDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Dog
    count_hit = True
```

Viewing individual animals works fine and view counts go up. Now on a main page, I need to list each animal type by most viewed. I can get the list of dogs, but how do I sort it by hit_count?

```
class AllAnimalsView(TemplateView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["dogs"] = Dogs.objects.all().order_by("-hit_count.hits")
        ....
        return context
```

This gives:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'hit_count.hits' in 'order clause'")`

Comment: I've gotten around this by converting the QS to a list, creating a list of view counts and using the view count list to sort the data list. But this seems inefficient to me...